# Check the type of a required module and if it returns right object based on its type

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

In a nodejs contest i would like to leave free the choice of how to write typescript modules (or even javascript) that perform operations on an observable. However, I need to know what type of function has been chosen in order to be able to use the right operator on the observable. The question is better understood by looking at the example:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap, map } from "rxjs/operators";

function attachOperation( in$:Observable<MyObject>, modulePath:string ):Observable<MyObject>{

  //types of modules that can be loaded
  type ObservableOperation = ( x: Observable<MyObject> ) => Observable<MyObject>
  type PromiseOperation = (x: MyObject ) => Promise<MyObject>
  type FunctionOperation = (x: MyObject ) => MyObject

  const operation = require(modulePath)

  let outObservable:Observable<MyObject>

  if( /* is ObservableOperation type */ ){

    outObservable = operation(in$)

  }else if( /* is PromiseOperation type */ ){

    outObservable = in$.pipe( concatMap( myObj => operation( myObj ) ) )

  }else if( /* is FunctionOperation type */ ){

    outObservable = in$.pipe( map( myObj => operation(myObj) ) )

  }else{

    throw new Error('not valid operation module')

  }

  return outObservable

}
```

How can i check (in the if statements) what type of module was loaded?

Edit: i also need to throw an error if the module does not returns the right object based on its type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript isn't capable of runtime type-checking, so while a solution to the problem as you describe could be possible, I would still suggest making your problem/solution less 'clever'.

"Dynamic" solutions often seem very appealing, but successfully implementing them is rarely worth the hassle. For instance, you could probably get the result you want with static analysis of the TypeScript imports combined with custom code generation to bring that type data into runtime. But I would guess you really don't want to go down that road.

You could achieve similar results by tying behavior to the import path, e.g. exports from paths resembling `src/function/**/*.js` are handled as functions, exports from `src/observable/**/*.js` are handled as observable factories, etc.

Error handling becomes simpler here too. You can throw if you call an exported function and it doesn't return the sort of value you expect.

Comment: as you say, it's not worth it. I have already abandoned the idea and created a template for how operations should be written